# How do you calculate the mid-point between two CGAffineTransform scale transforms?

Tags: cocoa, math, uikit, core-graphics, appkit

This might be more of a math question than a programming question, but in this example it's within the context of `CGAffineTransform.`

If you have two transforms that each represent a scaling transform, how do you calculate a mid-point between the two that would *visually* represent "half way" to the user?

For example:

```
CGAffineTransform minimumScale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
CGAffineTransform maximumScale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(10, 10);
```

Creating a transform with a scale factor of 5 does not produce the result I would like because going from `1 -> 5` represents a "5x magnification" from the user's perspective but going from `5 -> 10` only represents a "2x magnification".

In this trivial example, a scale factor of roughly `3.33` would produce the result I'm looking for as it would transform a frame like so:

```
W:100 x H:100 -> 333 x 333 // A 3x magnification from the user's perspective
W:333 x H:333 -> 999 x 999 // Also a 3x magnification from the user's perspective
```

However, the math formula eludes me for calculating this value given any two minimum and maximum scale values (of which the minimum could be less than 1.0, e.x.: `0.2 -> 3.9`).

Comment: You could try the geometric mean of the scale factors, (i.e. sqrt(scale1*scale2) so in your case sqrt(10)) rather then the arithmetic mean. With the geometric mean it is the ratio that is constant, i.e. gmean/smaller = greater/gmean rather than differences with the arithmetic mean: amean-smaller=greater-amean.

Comment: @dmuir That's not a bad suggestion and the results are passable for now. Thank you.